# Installing the Ubuntu Touch Terminal App on Desktop

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-touch

Is there currently a way to install the terminal app from Ubuntu Touch on Ubuntu Desktop 16.04?

[As seen here](http://design.canonical.com/2016/08/convergent-terminal/?utm_source=omgubuntu)

[And the app download is here](https://uappexplorer.com/app/com.ubuntu.terminal)

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using? I think it's possible with unity 8 with mir, not sure about others.

Comment: @pomsky I am using unity 7 so maybe not possible.